# How to disable Pentadactyl per site?

Tags: firefox, vim, vimperator, pentadactyl

Is there a more definitive way to disable Pentadactyl on a url basis that is **not** `-- PASS THROUGH --` ?

When I try to use codepen.io I cannot edit any text fields, with or without pass-through enabled. Any ideas that are not as drastic as going to the add-ons page to disable Pentadactyl would be greatly appreciated. I know Vimperator has this feature, does Pentadactyl?

Comment: Which Vimperator feature do you mean? I don't think Vimperator has any features Pentadactyl doesn't, so it should be available. Also, what exactly is happening when you try to edit CodePen text fields? I can edit them fine, with or without pass-through mode. But in pass-through mode, Pentadactyl shouldn't interfere with any of the site's bindings except `<Esc>` and `<C-v>`. That's what I normally use when I want access to a site's bindings.

Comment: @pyrocrasty If I remember correctly `shift + escape` will disable Vimperator temporarily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think pass-through will work for you if entered early enough.  I've discovered on Google Docs that if I manually enter passthough I still can't type, but if I reload the page with pass-through enabled things work.

You can take advantage of pentadactyl's `:autocmd` feature to run the pass-through command automatically based upon a URL regex.  For example, to disable pentadactyl on Google Docs you would enter the command

```
:autocmd LocationChange 'https://docs.google.com/*' :normal! <C-z>
```

You can make these changes permanent by saving these commands to your `.pentadactylrc` file.

Comment: I think pass-through will work for you if entered early enough.  I've discovered on google docs that if I manually enter passthough I still can't type but if I reload the page with pass-through enabled things work.

Comment: This is crucial and should be added to the answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable certain keys for a site, you can use `passkeys`. For example,

```
:set passkeys+=codepen.io:<Esc>
```

will pass the Escape key through on CodePen.

If you give me more details, I might be able to give a better answer. You really should be able to use CodePen with or without passthrough-mode enabled. (You'll want it enabled if you use CodePen's vi bindings.)