# How to get Pentadactyl to work with Google Docs

Tags: firefox-extensions, google-docs, pentadactyl

It appears to be a well-documented fact that Google Docs does not work when using Pentadactyl (I believe it's some kind of focusing issue).

I've spent many hours googling about this, and have yet to find a working solution.

The best solution I've found is `:autocmd LocationChange 'https://docs.google.com/*' :normal! <C-z>` (from 
[How to disable Pentadactyl per site?](https://superuser.com/questions/937218/how-to-disable-pentadactyl-per-site/944317#944317)), but that has multiple issues:

- It disables Pentadactyl altogether, which is a bit heavy-handed and makes it impossible to use for example `gt`.
- When switching tabs back and forth a few times, this "solution" stops working altogether, requiring me to reload the page.
- It's just a workaround, not a proper solution.

Comment: Have you tried using an alternative such as Vimperator or QuteBrowser?

Comment: It's quite possible that at the moment there is no somewhat simple solution.

Comment: @timotree Then I'd have to relearn everything again...

Comment: @Caagr98 I thought QuteBrowser and Pentadactyl had the same commands. I don't use either of them though so I may be wrong.

Comment: @timotree The keys might be the same, but I don't think Qute supports Firefox extensions, and some of those are pretty useful.

Comment: That wouldn't work out then.